# What is the easiest way to display author information on channel entries in a template?

Tags: channel-entries, templates

In EE 2.7.2,

If you have a channel where there are various authors to different articles, is there a way using the full version of EE to simply show some fields based on the author?  The goal would be to display custom author fields.  The code might look something like what you see below.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="articles" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="10"}
    <a href="{title_permalink='channel/comments'}">{title}</a><br>
    <div>{author_name}|{author_favorite_sport}</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I do have Solspace User installed, as well as my own custom module, but it just seems that I'm overthinking this somehow.

TIA for any help!

Answer (score 3):

You'd do it precisely as you have done.

If you use the custom member fields within a channel entries tag loop then you will output information about the author of the entry being displayed.

You don't need any custom add-ons to do this.